# App crashes inside android sdk during transition

Tags: android, android-fragments

I faced with strange problem. Sometimes app crashes during navigating from one fragment to another. There is stack trace for exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1012)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:971)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2143)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I use support library version 25.2.0. Crash is random so I cannot reproduce it every time. Any help?

Comment: Fragment object returns null

Answer (score 0):

With getSupportFragmentManager() you are getting the supportLibrary fragmentManager instead of the systems fragmentManager. So you are working with a transaction of the supportlibrary.

This is the reason why you need to add all these imports and use android.support.v4.app.

If you want to get the systems fragmentManager just try to use getFragmentManager() instead getSupportFragmentManager()